# Any solutions on why my program returns the wrong answer?

Tags: c

I was going through C Programming: A Modern Approach and came to assignments and declarations with a program at the bottom, I copied it word for word and it doesn't give me the expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int height, length, width, volume, weight;

    height = 8;
    length = 12;
    width = 10;
    volume = height * weight * width;
    weight = (volume + 165) / 166;

    printf("Dimensions %d x %d x %d\n",length, width, height);
    printf("Volume (cubic inches) : %d\n",volume);
    printf("Dimensional weight (pounds) : %d\n", weight);

    return 0;
}
```

The output that I get from the program is:

```
Dimensions 12 x 10 x 8
Volume (cubic inches) : 0
Dimensional weight (pounds) : 0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I ran this in Xcode and it doesn't have any errors with the program yet still prints this. Any solutions on why this code isn't working?

Comment: Yes, I copied straight from the IDE

Answer (score 7):

You don't initialize `weight` before using it in the expression for `volume`. That causes undefined behavior. And it appears that your *volume* formula is wrong, you should write

```
volume = height * length * width;
```

I think.

Enable compiler warnings and you should avoid this kind of silly mistake, don't take it the wrong way they are common when you are coding and that's why warning messages are so helpful.

Comment: Thanks that was the mistake that I made.

Comment: Yes, also think about the meaning of what you are doing. `volume = height * weight * width;` cannot possibly be right.

Comment: @WeatherVane specially when good variable naming was used, that should reduce this kind of problem a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The formula was [*volume*](http://www.basic-mathematics.com/volume-formulas.html) was incorrect.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int height = 8;
    int length = 12;
    int width = 10; 
    int volume = height * length * width;
    int weight = (volume + 165) / 166;

    printf("Dimensions %d x %d x %d\n", length, width, height);
    printf("Volume (cubic inches) : %d\n", volume);
    printf("Dimensional weight (pounds) : %d\n", weight);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No circular dependency involved! What are you talking about?. If `weight` is initialized before `volume` this is completely valid. Whereas circular dependency is a very different concept.

Comment: Do these not both depend on eachother? `volume = height * weight * width;` `weight = (volume + 165) / 166;` Though I get what your're saying, it will still function, just not as intended. I will revise